# Git changes and authors not showing above functions and property

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022.When I used it can't see the number of changes or authors name above functions, properties, and classes.
[image]
I used Visual Studio 2019 many. When using it ii show me the status above every function or class.
but here I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Open Options, go to Text Editor -> All Languages -> Code Lens and make sure Show Authors & Changes (Git) is checked. Of course you also need a git repository for that project.

Comment: no option called Show Authors & Changes(Git) in that path

Comment: then you probably run the Community Edition which according to the docs does not have this feature

Answer (score 1):

@Piglet mentioned correct path. Make sure if you VS2022 has CodeLens available under `All Languages`.

Screenshot: [From Tools menu, open Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFuCl.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33586425)